# Tengo problemas con el operador "if" en las igualaciones en C++

Tags: c++, condiciones

He tenido problemas con vario de mis problemas en las comparaciones por igualacion, para buscar contenido en un arreglo por ejemplo, pero de una u otra manera no logro ver cual es el problema, ya he intentado muchas cosas, pero no logro ver el problema.

El codigo que estoy probando es parte de uno mas grande en donde buscas un valor dentro de un arreglo, y hasta donde pude ver, el problema es en esta funcion que lo que hace es que a partir de 3 datos:
el valor buscado ,el tamaño del arreglo, el arreglo.

El problema es que al comparar los numeros aunque se cumpla la condicion no ejecuta la asignacion dentro del if.

Intente al principio igualar directamente el valor buscado contra el valor en el arreglo, pero aunque fueran iguales, al parecer no funcionaba.

He intentado cambiar por otra variable para que no sea directo, pero sin exito.
mi ultimo intento es el siguiente,, esta lleno de couts para ver lo que sucede en cada parte.

Les agradeceeria que me iluminen con su sabiduria, seguramente esto es muy basico, pero estoy un poco desesperado.

Saludos

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int buscarValor(int val, int ene, int cadena[]){
    int f, x=5, val2, cero=0;
    cout<<val<<" <---- val"<<endl;
    for(f=0;f<ene;f++){
        cout<<cadena[f]<<" <---- cadena de for"<<endl;
        val2=cadena[f]-val;
        cout<<cadena[f]<<" cadena["<<f<<"] -> "<<cadena[f]<<" menos "<<val<<" es igual a "<<val2<<endl;
        if(val2 == cero){
            x=1;
        }
        else{
            x=0;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
int main ()
{
     int n=4, m, i, j, b;
     int cad[4]={2,1,9,4};
     
     cin>>m;
     
     j=buscarValor(m,n,cad);
     
     cout<<j<<" <---- resultado";
     
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: El condicional no es el problema, es la lógica. Si se cumple el condicional x sera 1, pero si para el siguiente item del array el condiciona no se cumple le asignas 0 de nuevo... Si quieres que retorne 1 debes romper el ciclo cuando el condicional se cumpla.

Comment: Y la idea es que devuelva `true` o `false` si el número está o no? Por qué no usas un `bool` entonces?

Comment: Aparte de eso, tampoco entiendo lo de la resta...  usando el mismo for ¿por que no simplemente algo como:    `for(...){if(cadena[f] == val) return true;} return false;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código *falla* porque cada iteración cambia el valor de `x`. Tal vez el elemento esté en la lista, pero las demás iteraciones lo restablecen:

```
if(val2 == cero){
    x=1;
}
else{
    x=0;
}
```

Al contrario, deberías establecer 0 como valor inicial y quitar la rama el `else`.

Por cierto, por qué crear una variable llamada 0? Con un solo caracter puedes hacer lo mismo que con 4. Y como comentó FJSevilla, por qué no simplemente haces así?

```
bool buscarValor(int valor, int largo, int cadena[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++){
        if (valor == cadena[i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```